# Firebase - Best way to get values from ref A with values from ref B?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A little hard to explain but i'll give it a go.

Basically i have two tables, one store locations and the other stores users. The flow while follow as:
 - Get locations as per query (completed)
 - Get users that match locations in the query

Currently i have all the corresponding keys from the locations to the users. What's the correct and fastest way to get the users details after getting the needed locations.

I'm not asking how to get users depending on the location as i have already referenced the user for the location, i was just wondering how i should execute getting the users details.
Should i create a second listener for users to get their details?

PS i'm new on firebase, all help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right and that is one way you could do it: The query might follow like this

```
final DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query locationQuery = root.child("location").orderByChild("place").equalTo("london");
    locationQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            // I am assuming you have your own custom location class that you push to firebase 
            Location location = dataSnapshot.getValue(Location.class);

            // make the second query inside the on Child Added method

            Query userQuery = root.child("users").orderByChild("location").equalTo(location);

            userQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    // again I am assuming you have your own custom user class
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                }

        }


}
```

I have just cut out all the other methods from the child event listeners. 
So you make the first query by location on you location table. Then for each location returned in the onChildAdded method you make another query to the users table and make a query by the returned location.